# iSCSIについて

Tags: ハードウェア

iSCSIの認識について正しいか教えてください。

すべて仮想環境、仮想マシンでの話なのですが、私はiSCSIとは、

1. ターゲットとなる仮想マシンのディスクからイニシエータが接続するためのストレージを切り出す
2. イニシエータは、ネットワークを通してそのターゲットとなるストレージを取得しにいく（接続する、マウントする）

ということだと認識していますが、間違っていますでしょうか？

例えば、もっと具体例を挙げるとしますと、あるサーバのストレージが10GBあるとします。その中から5GB分を切り出してiSCSIのターゲットとして用意します。イニシエータは、ターゲットのIPアドレス等を見てそれに接続しにいき、ターゲット（iSCSIストレージ）を自身のストレージとして利用することができるようになる。

こういうことではありませんか？

追記 : 本当のiSCSIとはちょっと違うのかな？と言われてしまいましたが、個人的にはネットワークを通してあるターゲットのストレージを自由にその他のイニシエータ（ある意味でクライアント）のマシンがそれを利用しにいくことができるシステムだと認識していました。

> 774RRさん

ありがとうございます。そのような歴史的経緯？があり、その認識の相違からうまく理解が得られなかったのだと理解しました。現在リモート接続で社内の仮想環境上で作業しておりまして、iSCSIでターゲットを用意しイニシエータから接続させたという話を伝えると、「それってiSCSIって言うのかな…？」と疑問符を持たれ、私自身もなかなかその疑問を持たれることに謎が深まる一方だったのですが、現在では仮想環境上のやり方（ディスクを切り出してターゲットとして用意してアクセスさせる）ということもiSCSIと呼ぶというお答えを提示頂きとてもスッキリしました。大変感謝致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iSCSI` は、もともとは仮想ではなくて物理の話で

- 既存の物理装置、ハードディスクやテープ (SCSI 装置) があって
- でもそれは手元にはない（＝ネットワークで接続した別マシンに接続されていて）
- 手元のマシンに直で接続されていたなら SCSI 手続きでそれらにアクセスするドライバがある

という状況であるなら

- 既存の物理層 (`UW-SCSI` や `SAS` や `eSATA` やその他) を Ether + TCP で代用する

と、今ある OS ([windows](/questions/tagged/windows) / [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)) やアプリケーションプログラムを一切いじることなく、設置済みネットワークを引き直すことなく、デバイスドライバをちょいと追加するだけで、遠隔マシンの記憶装置を手元にあるかのごとく使えるよね、って話です。

そこから１歩進めると、質問本文にあるように

- サーバー上の大規模記憶装置の一部をあたかも物理装置のごとく振る舞うように切り出せば
- クライアントから見て自分専用の記憶装置があるように取り扱える

だけのことです。その意味で質問に対する答えは前半も後半も Yes っす。

始まりは物理装置の遠隔接続だったけど、今は仮想装置の遠隔接続にも使われています、でヨシ！